# Supermicro IPMI card 3rd data port

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ipmi, supermicro

What does the `AOC-SIMLP-3(+)` SuperMicro IPMI-card have in favor of the `AOC-SIMLP-B(+)`?

I see that it has an additional LAN-Port, named as `3rd data port`, but what is it actually used for and what are the advantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used one of them but the way I read the [literature](http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/AOC-SIMLP.pdf) for this and the other 82541 IPMI cards is you can make use of the extra port available on the Intel 82541 PI Gigabit LAN chip as a normal OS accessible PCIe network card. The Intel LAN drivers are [provided for the cards](ftp://ftp.supermicro.com/CDR-SIMIPMI_1.13_for_SIM_IPMI/LAN/Intel/v10.4/). I read 3rd DATA LAN as being after the two normally included onboard SM X7 and H8 motherboards via an Intel controller.

As mentioned, no real world proof with these to back it up. SM will generally be helpful [for presales via email](http://www.supermicro.com/about/contact/)

Comment: Ah, okay! Where did you find this? - I searched the manual for it over and over again.

Comment: You're right it's not specifically stated, I meant that's what I interpreted when reading the guides (and seeing the drivers). I really can't think of a reason for having a specific IPMI 'data' port on top of a dedicated port either. But try email SM for clarification and let us know.

Comment: Answer from Supermicro: `The 2nd LAN port on AOC-SIMLP-3+ is a standard Ethernet port for the OS and is separate from the IPMI` - This proves that your assumption was right.